# VXV vs. VIX futures: arbitrage opportunities?

Tags: options, volatility, futures, vix, term-structure

At a first glance, VXV and VIX futures should not be compared at all: VXV is an underlying index, whilst VIX futures are derivatives written on a different underlying index, that is, VIX.

As instance, from a fixed income point of view, using VIX futures to seek opportunities on VXV seems like using EURIBOR 3M IRS to seek opportunities on EURIBOR 6M spot price: complete nonsense.

However, there's a point I am missing which puzzles me.

Follow my way of thinking:

- if I buy 2M VIX futures, two months later my contract will expire and
  converge to VIX spot price;
- if I replicate a VXV spot exposure
  through a carefully strike weighted straddle (see very famous [**More
  Than You Ever Wanted To Know About Volatility Swaps**](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ajacquie/IC_Volatility/IC_Volatility_Docs/Literature/Goldman_VarSwaps.pdf) by Goldman
  Sachs' guys), two months later my exposure will converge to a VIX
  exposure, because my strike weighted options chain is not anymore
  centered on 3M tenor but on 1M ~ 30D tenor.

Therefore I have two positions which deliver the same payoff at some point: no-arbitrage rules would say that they should price the same, which is not true.

VXV vs. generic 2nd CBOE VIX futures spread:

[image]

If VXV is worth 22.5 and VIX 2M futures is slightly above 20.5, could you explain why shorting VXV and long such futures would not return me $2$ points of risk free volatility earnings?

Answer (score 3):

VXV is a 3-month volatility index, and is currently not tradable (there are no futures on it). And since you cannot trade it, you cannot arb it.